# android запуск google map

Tags: android, google-maps-api, google-maps

Необходимо при запуске приложения проверить есть на устройстве google map и если есть, то запустить и отобразить маршрут, если нет то открыть браузер и также отобразить маршрут. [Есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435548/%D0%A0%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82-google-map-v2-android) пример, но мне он кажется достаточно громоздким, есть какое-то более короткое решение?
Как можно ускорить выполнение операции расчета маршрута?

Answer (score 5):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужно открыть маршрут в приложении `Google Maps`, или в браузере ,если приложение не установлено:

```
String url = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/ленина,33/ленина,15";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Этот код откроет диалог выбора приложения, при помощи которого будет открыта данная ссылка. Если установлен `Google Maps`, то он будет в списке приложений. Также в этом списке будут все установленные браузеры. Маршрут будет проложен из Ленина 33 к Ленина 15. Адресса не должны содержать пробелы, иначе в `Google Maps` маршрут не сработает.

Если вы хотите указать именно точки координатами, то укажите вместо адрессов координаты в таком формате:
`https://www.google.com/maps/dir/47.8964601,34.9789815/48.1589387,34.9065337`

Comment: Хорошо, а как строить маршрут? Т.е. есть две точки отправления и прибытия, куда их добавлять?

Comment: @AlexsandrTer, обновил ответ

Comment: Точно, я затупил. Спасибо